# Javascript: Cannot copy array and keep them sperate

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, copy

I am so confused. I want to take a and copy its value to b. But when I edit a or b, I do not want it to also edit b and a. Here is an example. When I add 'a' to the a variable, b should still remain as ['b', 'c'] but the console logs says it is ['a', 'b', 'c']. What am I doing wrong?

```
var a = ['b', 'c'];
var b = a;

a.unshift('a');

console.log(a)
console.log(b)
```

Comment: It is not a copy, you are referencing it.

Comment: have you done this? `var clone = originalArray.slice(0);`

Comment: You are referencing your array. Rewrite it to this: ```var b = [...a];```. The spread operator will make a new array and assign the values to it.

Comment: Google this:  javascript **deep copy.**  Consider this page:  https://we-are.bookmyshow.com/understanding-deep-and-shallow-copy-in-javascript-13438bad941c

Comment: not sure why everyone is repeating all the answers listed in the dupe. lol